# C# Generics: Modify hidden inherited member in derived class

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following class structure:

```
public class A {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A {
    public new string Name {
        get { return base.Name; }
        set { base.Name = value + " set in B"; }
    }
}

public static class Test {
    public static void SetAndPrintName<T>(T value, string name) where T : A {
        value.Name = name;

        Console.WriteLine(value.Name);
    }
}
```

Here's the result I would expect from running the following code:

```
Test.SetAndPrintName(new A(), "a");
Test.SetAndPrintName(new B(), "b");
----
a
b set in B
```

Instead, I get:

```
a
b
```

Since that didn't work, I tried casting `value` in `SetAndPrintName`, which is ugly but worked as expected:

```
public static void SetAndPrintName<T>(T value, string name) where T : A {
    if (value is B) {
        ((B)(object)value).Name = name;
    } else {
        value.Name = name;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(value.Name);
}
----
Test.SetAndPrintName(new A(), "a");
Test.SetAndPrintName(new B(), "b");
----
a
b set in B
```

I also tried making the `Name` property virtual/overridden and that worked too:

```
public class A {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A {
    public override string Name {
        get { return base.Name; }
        set { base.Name = value + " set in B"; }
    }
}
----
Test.SetAndPrintName(new A(), "a");
Test.SetAndPrintName(new B(), "b");
----
a
b set in B
```

The question is:  why doesn't `new` work like the others?  The generic method knows that `value` is of type `B`, so why does C# treat it as an `A` in one case out of three?

Comment: The `new` keyword doesn't inherently mean `virtual`. And Generic implementation won't change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The generic method knows that value is of type B

Not at compile-time it doesn't. When the compiler sees `value.Name`, it has to resolve that to *one* member... and the only member available to it is the one declared in `A`.

Think of your two properties as being *entirely separate* - as if they had different names. Let's call them `NameA` and `NameB`.

Your code is effectively:

```
public static void SetAndPrintName<T>(T value, string name) where T : A {
    value.NameA = name;
    Console.WriteLine(value.NameA);
}
```

That's valid, because the compiler can resolve `NameA` against `A`, and `T` is constrained to be an `A`.

If you try to explicitly use `NameB`, however:

```
// Invalid
public static void SetAndPrintName<T>(T value, string name) where T : A {
    value.NameB = name;
    Console.WriteLine(value.NameB);
}
```

... that won't work, because the compiler can't resolve `NameB` for `T`.

When you use a *virtual* property, then you've got a single declared member which has its *implementation* overridden in `B`... which is precisely what you normally do when you want to modify behaviour.

If you want to use different declared members based on execution-time type (without knowing it beforehand) you could use `dynamic`:

```
public static void SetAndPrintName(dynamic value, string name) {
    value.Name = name;
    Console.WriteLine(value.Name);
}
```

Comment: Aaaand I can stop writing on my answer :P

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense.  It didn't occur to me that `new` creates a *cough* new property instead of overriding the implementation in the existing one.  Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use dynamic keyword, you may introduce IA interface that both types inherit and use IA as type constraint for your generic method. That will produce the output you expect.

```
    public interface IA
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A : IA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A, IA
{
    public new string Name
    {
        get { return base.Name; }
        set { base.Name = value + " set in B"; }
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void SetAndPrintName<T>(T value, string name) where T : IA
    {
        value.Name = name;

        Console.WriteLine(value.Name);
    }
}
```